# Can we fit discrete data to a continuous distribution?

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data

why some studies fit the discrete data to a continuous distribution? For example,

the rainfall data used in the study are discrete but Gamma and GEV distributions are used to fit the data
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022169414008348)

What is the theory behind it? Where I can read more about it?

Comment: 1. Why do you think rainfall is discrete, other than at the "0" level?  2. The link to the paper isn't helpful for those of us who aren't ScienceDirect members, as it's behind a paywall, so it's best if you describe the issue in some detail yourself rather than referring us to the paper.

Comment: "Since the seasonal SPI values based on rainfall data used in the study are discrete, Gamma distribution and Generalized Extreme Value distribution (GEV) are used in this study. These distributions are frequently used to fit the distribution of droughts and floods (Shiau, 2006, Mathier et al., 1992)." Looking at it, I'm not sure why they say this is discrete. Researching SPI I find, "The Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI; McKee 1993) is the number of standard deviations that observed cumulative precipitation deviates from the climatological average."

Comment: 1. Idk to treat the rainfall duration as a continuous or discrete. The actual duration is continuous but after using SPI or IETD to extract the rainfall variables, I think it is discrete? 2. I want to find what distribution fits the duration data and I read many papers that fit the data to continuous distribution. Can I fit discrete data to a continuous distribution? or it is continuous data? @jbowman

Comment: Although the *data* might be discrete, the *model* for them need not be. This shows up in diverse places. One of the most extreme is a formulation of logistic regression, where the data are just zeros and ones--as discrete as you can get--but the model for them is based on a Normally distributed (but hidden) variable.  Thus, there are many possible answers to your question.